# BorderPane.getCenter() literally gets the node from the center region of BorderPane

Tags: java, javafx, borderpane

I noticed that BorderPane.getCenter() removes the node that it returns from the region where it is placed. What I'm trying to do is to mirror the child inside the center of BorderPane and put it into another BorderPane to check if my code(attempt of memory releasing when if a tab is not selected by setting it to null) is working. Here is my code:

```
TabPane.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs,ov,nv)-{

    //checks if "MyTab" tab is selected
    if (nv.getText().equals("MyTab")) {
        try {
                MyTabBP.setCenter(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MyTab.fxml")));
                MirrorBP.setCenter(MyTabBP.getCenter());
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(FXMLDocumentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

      //  else {
      //      MyTabBP.setCenter(null);
      //  }

    });
```

What I noticed (when I commented out the else block) is that after clicking MyTab, the BorderPane MyTabBP would be empty, and after checking MirrorBP(that is at another Tab), that is where the fxml that I loaded in MyTabBP was inserted into. After checking the BorderPane documentation, it said that

> getCenter()
>   Gets the value of the property center.

So I thought that it would just replicate everything that is inside the center of MyTabBP. So my question is how could I mirror the contents of a region(top, left, bottom, right, center) of a BorderPane? And hopefully that once a change happened at the node, it would update those who is referencing to it. So that I could test if this is actually working.

```
MyTabBP.setCenter(null);
```

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: *"I noticed that `BorderPane.getCenter()` removes the node"* nope. However a node can only be used in a single place of a single scene and `MirrorBP.setCenter()` removes the node passed to it from the old parent and puts it into the new one. You need to load the fxml twice, if you want to display the same scene twice and be able to interact with both scenes.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks for that information! I didn't knew that a node can only be used in a single place of a single scene. One additional question though, how could I actually check, that if I switch tabs, MyTabBP.getCenter(); would actually be null?

Comment: And also does MyTabBP.setCenter(null); releases the memory consumed by loading the fxml file?

Comment: As long as all other references to the node are removed the node should become available for garbage collection. If you want to be sure you could keep [a soft reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ref/SoftReference.html) to it, try to make the garbage collector claim it (`System.gc()`) and then check via the `SoftReference`, if the object was claimed (`SoftReference.get` returns `null`).